# jdk installer for windows 7 does not set path

Tags: java, javac

It seems the JDK installer on Windows 7 does not install a path variable to find javac. I can set it manually. But I do not like to change it with any new update of JDK. Does it use any other environment variable? Or is it really that weird?

Comment: You have more than ten questions you haven't accepted.

Comment: And what does that mean? How do I accept questions? You mean accept answers?

Comment: I report that the Java 7 RE also not setting path variable....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a JDK installer which sets the PATH on any system.

You can install several version of the JDK and if you use an IDE, you don't need to set the path.  If you want to use `javac` manually (don't ask me why you would) you need to set the PATH to specific which version to use.

Comment: +1 - Indeed, since JDKs and JREs installers are designed to make it easy to have multiple versions installed, it would be WRONG for the installer to mess with system-wide or user-specific PATH settings.

Comment: Yesterday I installed the Java runtime on a Windows 7 system, and it did not even set the path to javaw.exe.

Comment: AFAIK, It doesn't set the PATH on any OS.  You have to decide which version you want.

Comment: I use javac manually all the time. It's great for test compiling simple classes without the overhead of starting up a big IDE.

Comment: @Antimony An IDE takes a few second to start and will save you in productivity and improved quality of code far more.

Comment: @Peter I don't know about you, but Eclipse takes 103 seconds just to start up on my computer. For simple code examples, I can write, compile, and run the whole thing faster than that.

Comment: @Antimony on my laptop IntelliJ takes 70 seconds, but it's not something I do every day.  But I do compile, test and debug my program more than once per day.  I also use the static analysis and auto-fix as I type and code re-factoring as I type which I have measured to reduce the number of key pressed by 40%. One hit at the start of the day is worth all that I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can using environment variables. Which available in Control panel -> system